# While iterating through an array of associative arrays, does PHP's foreach order iterations by key instead of index?

Tags: php

I am having troubling using `foreach` with an array of associative arrays, where the keys in the associative arrays are numbers.

```
$rows = $_POST["row"];
// print_r($rows);
foreach ($rows as $r) {
    fwrite($f, $r["date"]);
    fwrite($f, "#");
    fwrite($f, $r["desc-short"]);
    fwrite($f, "#");
    // etc.
}
```

The POST variable contains arrays identified by `row[index]`.  If I stick in a `print_r()` it displays the POST values in the order they appeared in the original form (which is not necessarily numerical order, as rows can be inserted in the middle and the counter represents when they were added, not where), but when I iterate with `foreach` it ends up printing `row[8]` (assuming eight rows) last, even though it was inserted after row 2 (for example).

It seems that because my keys are numbers, `foreach` is treating the keys as if they were the order.  How can I avoid this behavior?

Output of example data from `print_r($rows)`:

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [date] => 12/12/2013 [desc-short] => Show title [desc-long] => A sample long description [start-time] => 12:30 [duration] => 13 [rating] => TVY ) [2] => Array ( [date] => 12/12/2013 [desc-short] => TEST [desc-long] => TEST [start-time] => 12:45 [duration] => 14 [rating] => TVY ) [8] => Array ( [date] => 12/12/2013 [desc-short] => Calendar of Events [desc-long] => A list of local events displayed every hour on the hour [start-time] => 13:00 [duration] => 15 [rating] => TVY ) [3] => Array ( [date] => 12/12/2013 [desc-short] => Show title [desc-long] => A sample long description [start-time] => 12:45 [duration] => 12 [rating] => TVY ) [4] => Array ( [date] => 12/12/2013 [desc-short] => Calendar of Events [desc-long] => A list of local events displayed every hour on the hour [start-time] => 13:00 [duration] => 15 [rating] => TVY ) [5] => Array ( [date] => 12/12/2013 [desc-short] => Show title [desc-long] => test [start-time] => 13:15 [duration] => 100 [rating] => TVY ) [6] => Array ( [date] => 12/12/2013 [desc-short] => Calendar of Events [desc-long] => A list of local events displayed every hour on the hour [start-time] => 15:00 [duration] => 15 [rating] => TVY ) )
```

And yes, 7 is missing. I'll have to look into that as well.  Rows number 1-6 were loaded from a file, while [8] was added in their midst later with JavaScript.

Comment: foreach() should iterate over the array in the order that print_r() or var_dump() displays: arrays are only sorted by key if you explicitly sort them. The order in which the array is passed through to PHP from the HTML POST request is outside of PHP's control

Comment: @MarkBaker I don't see how this could be the case, because print_r() and foreach() do not result in the same order.  The posted variables ARE out of order initially, and then foreach() prints the associated values by order of the keys.

Comment: There's clearly something wrong here: I've stated how foreach() is __meant__ to work; but can't explain why this isn't the case for you: Can you post the results of a var_dump() or print_r() of $rows?

Comment: @MarkBaker I updated the question with the print_r() output.  I think I might try to work around this issue (whatever it is) by making sure the rows are numbered in order of appearance before I submit the form.

Comment: @MarkBaker I misunderstood what JimDini was saying in his answer, but I've tried that now and it works. Identifiers such as row[a8] prevent the problem I was having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't avoid this if your keys are stuck like this. That's just how PHP works. If you need to maintain the order then you'll need to prefix numbers with letter